# Sending a message to a server and printing the reply

Tags: perl, sockets, tcp, telnet

I am working on a small assignment and am stuck on a step. I have successfully written a small tcp server/client, but I have to register it in our directory server. In order to do so, I need to send a message to the DS which will reply with "200 Success."

When I do this with telnet in terminal, I connect to the server, pass my message, and terminal spits back "200 Success." Now when I do this in Perl, I open a socket (succesfully) and send my message as (where $reg is my socket name).

```
print $reg "Message goes here";
```

I tried adding:

```
print <$reg>;
```

to get the server reply with no luck. I am a little stuck as I am unsure of how to get this message back, and am unsure if it is sending correctly. Here is my socket, with the leading sub call before it:

```
# Server registration
print &register . "\n";

sub register {
my $reg = IO::Socket::INET->new (
    PeerHost    =>  "server goes here",
    PeerPort    =>  port goes here,
    Proto       =>  $protocol
) or die "Failed to make socket for directory registration: $!\n";
print $reg "Register <my name> $ipaddr $port" . '\r'; #with required carriage return, this works in telnet too
my $msg = <$reg>;
print $msg;
```

}

Comment: Did you flush the stream? Unless your handle is set up as `autoflush` and depending on the actual message, your message might not have been sent because it's still in the buffer. I had a problem like that when I was dealing with a message protocol that didn't use line-endings.

Comment: I have a `|$ = 1` at the beginning of my script, that should be taking care of autoflush, right? I am still relatively new to perl.

Comment: Yeah that should do it--unless there is some other part of the code undoing it. Try an explicit flush and see if you get any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my message did not have the right syntax. When using telnet I was passing \r at the end, when I hit return it added the \n which is what the server needed. In Perl I only passed the \r. Since no \n was added, and no return key entered in my keyboard, the server was simply refusing the message.

Thank you to those that helped me!